# C# Open PDF file with Certificate Security

Tags: c#, security, pdf, certificate, itext

I am trying to open a PDF file with certificate security using the iText library. I keep getting this exception

> 'iTextSharp.text.exceptions.InvalidPdfException' occurred in itextsharp.dll
>   Additional information: /DefaultCryptFilter not found (encryption)

```
 var pdf = @"Y:\Return Authorization Forms\Saved Forms\ReturnAuthorizationForm LIVINGSTON.pdf";
        string cert= @"C:\Users\eflores\desktop\certt.cer";    

        X509Certificate2 Xcert = new X509Certificate2(cert);

        PdfReader read = new PdfReader(pdf);
```

The PDFReader class has one constructor that allows me to pass a certificate but its from a different class and I am not sure on how to use it because it also takes other parameters:

```
public PdfReader(
    string filename,
    X509Certificate certificate,
    ICipherParameters certificateKey
)
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: what does the using look like at the top of your .cs file where you are trying to consume the namespace / dll assembly.? are you using this assembly here http://opensourcejavaphp.net/csharp/itextsharp/PdfReader.cs.html

Comment: Hello @DJKRAZE, I am responsible for all the official iText products. I do not know the assembly you refer to. iText is a registered trademark. Please do not talk about iText or related products when referring to unofficial sources of the software.

Comment: As for the question: when certificate encryption is used to encrypt a PDF, the document is encrypted using somebody's **public key**. When you want to decrypt such a file, you need the corresponding **private key**. That is the whole purpose of encryption. Unfortunately, I do not see you provide access to the private key anywhere (only to the `.cer` file with the public key). If you do not have access to the private key, **you should never be able to decrypt the file.** If you could, there would a serious security problem as this would mean that no encrypted file is secure.

Comment: So the real question is: do you have the keystore that contains the private key that corresponds with your `certt.cer`? If not, you are never going to be able to decrypt the document.

Comment: Bruno, I do have the private key, I am just not sure how to implement it in the function when reading the pdf file.